# sbt-javaagent + jmx_exporter + sbt run seems to do nothing

Tags: scala, sbt, javaagents, jmx-exporter

I'd like to add the JMX Exporter java agent to my sbt project. I'm using [sbt-javaagent](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-javaagent) and [jmx_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter)

As far as I can tell I'm configuring them correctly in `build.sbt`, but it has no effect - the metrics aren't available at the expected URL on localhost, and if I configure it with an invalid port number, which according to the source code should cause `jmx_exporter` to throw an exception, nothing happens. So I suspect it's not actually getting added as a java agent, and I'm unclear how to best debug this. Any help would be appreciated.

Added to `project/plugins.sbt` (I included sbt-native-packager just to follow the readme exactly - including/excluding it has no effect on the behavior I'm seeing):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-javaagent" % "0.1.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.7.6")
```

Relevant section of `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, SwaggerPlugin, JavaAgent, JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.h2database"      % "h2"                    % "1.4.200",
      "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick"                 % "3.3.3",
      "com.typesafe.play"  %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "5.0.0",
      "org.postgresql"      % "postgresql"            % "42.2.12"
    ),
    javaAgents ++= Seq(jmxExporterJavaAgent)
  )

lazy val jmxExporterJavaAgent = {

  val port = 9090
  val conf = "conf/jmx_exporter_conf.yaml"

  val arguments = s"${port}:${conf}"

  val agent = JavaAgent(
    "io.prometheus.jmx" % "jmx_prometheus_javaagent" % "0.14.0" % "compile;test",
    arguments = arguments)

  println(s"jmx_exporter args: '${arguments}'")
  println(s"Adding JavaAgent: ${agent}")
  println(s"JavaAgent.arguments = '${agent.arguments}'")
  println(s"jmx exporter metrics should be available at http://localhost:${port}/metrics")

  agent
}
```

In a terminal:

```
sbt run
```

outputs:

```
...
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
jmx_exporter args: '9090:conf/jmx_exporter_conf.yaml'
Adding JavaAgent: AgentModule(jmx_prometheus_javaagent,io.prometheus.jmx:jmx_prometheus_javaagent:0.14.0:javaagent,AgentScope(false,true,true,true),=9090:conf/jmx_exporter_conf.yaml)
JavaAgent.arguments = '=9090:conf/jmx_exporter_conf.yaml'
jmx exporter metrics should be available at http://localhost:9090/metrics
...
(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)
```

in another terminal:

```
curl http://localhost:9090/metrics
```

outputs

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9090: Connection refused
```

If I then provide an invalid port to jmx exporter:

```
  val port = "invalid"
```

`sbt run` produces this output as expected:

```
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
jmx_exporter args: 'invalid:conf/jmx_exporter_conf.yaml'
Adding JavaAgent: AgentModule(jmx_prometheus_javaagent,io.prometheus.jmx:jmx_prometheus_javaagent:0.14.0:javaagent,AgentScope(false,true,true,true),=invalid:conf/jmx_exporter_conf.yaml)
JavaAgent.arguments = '=invalid:conf/jmx_exporter_conf.yaml'
jmx exporter metrics should be available at http://localhost:invalid/metrics
```

but does not throw an `IllegalArgumentException` as expected.

The line of code I expected to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in jmx exporter is this one:
https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/src/main/java/io/prometheus/jmx/JavaAgent.java#L54

because "invalid" would not match the regex in that code that parses the arguments.

This implies to me that the jmx_exporter java agent is simply never started, so there's something wrong with how I'm using sbt-javaagent.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish exactly the same -- instrument prometheus on a play app, and also having a hard time. If you have been able to get it to work, do you mind sharing your setup?